# Different controls for different (base)layouts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I have different `Layout`'s in my shared folder and different user controls.
Depending on the `Layout` it should render a different control.

What I did before:

**ViewItem.cshtml(different controls)**

```
     @helper h3(string dataBind = "", string other = "", string cssClass = "", string id = "")
        {
            @System.Web.WebPages.WebPageContext.Current.Page.RenderPage("~/UserControls/Elements/h3.cshtml", dataBind, other, cssClass, id)
        }
```

**h3.cshtml**

```
    @inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage

    @*
        PageData[0]: dataBind value
        PageData[1]: other  , different attributes
        PageData[2]: cssClass value
        PageData[3]: id value
    *@

    //In this file I would like to check wether it will be rendered in 
    @if (Layout.Contains("boots") {
    <h3 id="@PageData[3]" class="@PageData[2]" data-bind="@PageData[0]" @Html.Raw(PageData[1])></h3>
    }else{
    <h3 >No Bootstrap</h3 >
    }
```

**DataToShow.cshtml**(here the heading should be displayed reagarding layout)

```
  @ViewItem.h3("text: Title")
```

Depending on the Layout, it should rendere a different control

By the way what do you think about this approach(using this kind of controls), what could I do better ?

Thank you

ps. He doesn't format my code...

Comment: mmh, what could be the solution ...